# PHPUnit - mock method of class use created instance

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, instantiation

I want to mock a method `foo` in a class but leave method `bar` as it is:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    protected $dep1;
    protected $dep2;
    protected $dep3;
    protected $dep4;

    /**
     * Test constructor.
     * @param $dep1
     * @param $dep2
     * @param $dep3
     * @param $dep4
     */
    public function __construct($dep1, $dep2, $dep3, $dep4)
    {
        $this->dep1 = $dep1;
        $this->dep2 = $dep2;
        $this->dep3 = $dep3;
        $this->dep4 = $dep4;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        return "foo";
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

However, `MyClass` is instantiated via a factory which retrieves the dependencies (`$dep1`, `$dep2`, ...) and inject them directly in to the constructor of `MyClass`.
So I want to use that Factory and instantiate a MyClass-object (otherwise the complex instantiation has to be coded in the test case also).

In short I want to know if there is another solution than:

```
class TestMyClass extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    public function setUp()
    {
        // complicated way to retrieve $dep1 to $dep4

        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(MyClass::class)->setMethods(['foo'])->setConstructorArgs([$dep1, $dep2, $dep3, $dep4])->getMock();
        $mock->expects($this->any())->method('foo')->willReturn(false);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to somehow create proxy to an already created instance of `MyClass`, which just overrides the `foo` method? Is there another way (without runkit pecl extension) to mock an method of an existing/instantiated object?

I know PHPUnit has some `Proxy`-related methods, but I couldn't find any documentation / example of usage of them, so I am not sure if they even could be used to solve my problem.

Comment: Can't you also mock the dependencies? instead of using a _complicated_ way of getting them?

Comment: well yes, but this is somehow a Integration Test. So I need the dependencies to do their jobs...

Comment: I've seen this solved by reusing (instead of copy/pasting) the Factory class. A `TestFactory` extending the `OriginalFactory` can be used to setup your tests, but also minimize rewriting of the original code again.